# VS 2019, Tensorflow 2.6 C++, tensorflow::TensorInfo name() leads to The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, tensorflow, dll, linker, tensorflow2.x

I'm having a C++ project where I'm loading a Saved Model and want to do some inference. Now I have the followin code:

```cpp
    Status status = LoadSavedModel(session_options, run_options, "final", { kSavedModelTagServe }, &model_bundle);
    auto sig_map = model_bundle.GetSignatures();
    auto model_def = sig_map.at("serving_default");
    for (auto const& p : model_def.inputs()) {
        std::cout << p.first.c_str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.second.name() << std::endl;
    }
```

This snippet leads to the following error message when I execute a successfully built exe file:

```
The procedure entry point  could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

If I comment `//std::cout << p.second.name() << std::endl;` out, everything compiles well and executable runs as well. Since, p.second is of type `tensorflow::TensorInfo` I also tried to create such object and call `ti.name();` which also leads to the same problem.

Can you suggest any idea on how to fix this? Was the compilation of tensorflow_cc.dll somewhat incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very straightforward. When you compile tensorflow you have to manually add missing exported symbols to `tensorflow_filtered_def_file.def` and relink tensorflow.dll. Once, after relinking the tensorflow.dll and compiling my own program depending on this dll, I forgot to copy the new tensorflow.dll to the location where I was testing my program. So the new executable was unable to work with the previously compiled tensorflow.dll, but since it knew all the symbols it showed empty symbol in the error message.

Solution: make sure that you use the same tensorflow.dll when you run your program as it was during the compilation of your program.